# How To Save an Item List in rows in session and display it on the Template in django

Tags: python, ajax, django

Kindly assist with my plight as am still new to django python.

Am developing a shopping cart application, where ajax receives the cart items and send it via POST to View in django

- in Django View

  ```
   def add_product (request):
       if is_ajax or request.POST:
           productname = request.POST.get('productname','')
           price = request.POST.get('price')
           quantity = request.POST.get('quantity', '')
           cartsession = request.session.get('cartitems', {})
           cartsession[productname] = productname
           cartsession[price] = price
           cartsession[total] = total
           cartsession[quantity] = quantity

           request.session.get('cartitem') = cartsession
           return render(request, 'cartset.html',{'cartsession':cartsession})
  ```

on Template

```
{% for cart in cartsession %}

  { cart.productname}

{% endfor %}
```

After the code above nothing is displaying on the Template page...

Someone pls help

Comment: Do you have a models.py?  If you create a variable `v = Cart()`, or whatever your model is, then you should just be able to call `v.save()`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code,

views.py

```
cartsession['productname'] = productname
cartsession['price'] = price
```

To display dictionary value by key in template,

```
{{ cartsession.price }}
{{ cartsession.productname }}
```

if you want to iterate through dictionary items, use the below code.

```
{% for key,value in cartsession.items %}
    {{ key }} : {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```